# need a beginner GWT tutorial to set up & develop a baic web app using eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I need a beginner tutorial OR youtube video tutorial for start developing web applications using GWT with eclipse ide

Answer (score 2):

It is where you would expect it to be: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html

Comment: I am reading their Sample GWT App tutorial but it turned out to be little complex. Since I am just very beginner with GWT, I was looking for something bit simple.

Comment: Do you have a Java background? In my opinion, if you know the basics for RPC and GUI in Java, it is quite easy to start using GWT.

Comment: yes, I have Java back ground. Though I have not used any web framework before. So I was thinking like there may be some very simple start tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse and [Google Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/eclipse/) then use the blue New Web Application Project toolbar button and make sure the "Generate GWT project sample code" checkbox is checked in the New Web Application Project wizard. This produces an absolutely rudimentary GWT app with some widgets and Remote Procedure Calls. You can immediately run it and even use Eclipse debugging tools to see what's going on.

Comment: Right, that's actually the way I did it. I used the above mentioned tutorial only when something did not work out with trial and error. Unfortunately, I don't know about an even simpler way to start GWT.

Comment: @Teetrinker
thank you very much. I find this very simple one, 
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/usingeclipse.html